# Does adding a "while" change the meaning

Tags: prepositions

> There is plenty of work to be had catering for weddings and parties.

I think it is same as

> There is plenty of work to be had while catering for weddings and parties.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

The phrase **to be had** means "available".

There are many opportunities *available* for a wedding caterer.

We would not use the phrase **to be had** to describe the amount of work that must be done, just as we would not use the word "available" to describe that work.

> The room is such a mess.  There's plenty of tidying up **to be had**. <sup>NO</sup>

Rather, we would say

> There's plenty of tidying up **to be done**.

or

> There's plenty of tidying up **to do**.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite, there is a subtle difference between each sentence.

> There is plenty of work to be had catering for weddings and parties

This could be interpreted as meaning that for someone working as a wedding caterer, the market for their job is very active/buoyant.  In other words, "It is a good time to be a wedding caterer because *there is plenty of work to be had catering for weddings & parties*.

> There is plenty of work to be had while catering for weddings and parties

The difference here is the inclusion of while.  This means that during the act of catering, i.e. making cakes, cooking food and so on, there is plenty of work.  For example,

"I have been very busy cooking for a wedding today, there is plenty of work to be had while catering...."

The former implies there are many weddings that need catering, the latter implies once you are catering for a wedding, there is a lot that must be done.